# Unable to return the value in lambda expression using break condition

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to write a coding problem using java8 lambda expression. but when it coming to break from the loop, i am stuck.
**Note: i am aware that break can't be used inside the lambda expression. I tried to use
`findAny()` but didn't exactly know how to use that in my case here.**

```
        final boolean []flag = {true};
       IntStream.range(0,res.length).filter((i)->{
           if(res[i]>0){
               flag[0]=false;
                break;
           }
           else{
               flag[0]=true;
           }
       });
       return flag[0];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below construct to check if value of at least one element in `res` is greater than 0:

```java
IntStream.range(0, res.length).filter(i -> res[i] > 0).findAny().isPresent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [anyMatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), which returns `true` on the first result that matches the condition - or `false` if none:

```
 boolean match = IntStream.range(0, res.length).anyMatch(i -> res[i] > 0);
 flag[0] = match;
 return flag[0];
```

Comment: apparently you should return the result immediately, without setting match or flag[0].